# how to get the keys of sub array from this array tree

Tags: php

How to get the keys 151,152 from this nested array and store them as a separate array

```
Array  
   (  
    [151] => Array  
        ( 
            [152] => Array  
                (  
                )  

        )  

   )
```

Comment: Loop through the array using `foreach($array as $key=>$value)`, then save the key.  Repeat for the inner array.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php

Comment: @StrubT well very simple, he just asks a bunch of questions and never accepts any answer  ..

Answer (score 4):

```
function recursive_keys($input){ 
    $output = array_keys($input);
    foreach($input as $val){
        if (is_array($val)){
            $output = array_merge($output, recursive_keys($val));
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Recursive to extend the depth of arrays it can handle.

Links: [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php), [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

Comment: ... i think you might be missing a return statement

Comment: Whoops... let's not tell anybody about that.

Comment: Hi OhCaN,it was worked for me, but after slight modification foreach($input as $key =>$val) Thanks

Comment: Corrected. If it worked, mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $newArray[] = $key;
    foreach($val as $key2 => $val2){
        $newArray[] = $key2;
    }
}
```

Comment: why ? You would still need loop on them ...

Comment: Yes, but it would be more extensive. In case there's a new nested array in the nested array in the array.

Comment: But that is not the OP's question :)

Comment: But with a limited answer, more problems may ocurr.